# Episerver CMS 11 authentication endpoint

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I've just started exploring the Optimizely Content Delivery API. I have a confusing issue regarding the authentication process of the endpoint. I noticed in the documentation that there is an endpoint for authentication, but when I tried to use the Episerver.ContentDelivery.API.CMS 2.6.0, the authenticate endpoint cannot be found. I've searched for additional documentation to help me with this, but I couldn't find any. Can you please assist me with this?"

https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/class-libraries/rest-apis/content-delivery-api/content-delivery-api-2-6-1/#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install and setup `EPiServer.ContentDeliveryApi.OAuth`?

Also check https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/developer-guides/archive/content-delivery-api/configuration/configuration-v2/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I never thought there is an archive content.